# Wireguard no DNS response after connect

Tags: mac-osx, wireguard

I have the following setup:

- a local DNS server (unbound) listening on `10.10.20.1`
- a wireguard server on `10.10.0.1/24`
- a wireguard client on `10.10.0.2/32` with DNS pointed to `10.10.20.1`

I can connect to the server and I can see the peer:

```
peer: ..redacted
endpoint: 127.0.0.1:33218 
allowed ips: 10.10.0.2/32, 10.10.20.1/32 
latest handshake: 1 minute, 19 seconds ago 
transfer: 247.87 KiB received, 571.86 KiB sent 
persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

Once connected, I can issue dig commands on my terminal and they return ok:

```
dig u/10.10.20.1 reddit.com
;; Warning: query response not set

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> u/10.10.20.1 reddit.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27447
;; flags: rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;reddit.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
reddit.com.     0   IN  A   151.101.129.140
reddit.com.     0   IN  A   151.101.193.140
reddit.com.     0   IN  A   151.101.65.140
reddit.com.     0   IN  A   151.101.1.140

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 10.10.20.1#53(10.10.20.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 11 21:18:35 EEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

Once connected, ifconfig shows my interface up:

```
utun7: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1420
    options=6463<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    inet 10.10.0.2 --> 10.10.0.2 netmask 0xffffffff
```

But, my browser does not resolve anything, **nor does any other software on my system**.
Funnily enough, I have a VM with a Windows machine and...the internet works once connected.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the system is *BSD rather than Linux (which is often considered as default with WireGuard). You should state what is your OS in the tags. Also I don't understand why the endpoint would be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Edited the tags. The client is on MacOs. Server is on debian 10.  127.0.0.1 is just a udp forwarder that accepts connections from client and forwards them to the wireguard server port (it is needed due to some ACLs in place). That's why WG reports 127.0.0.1 as endpoint as that's the traffic source for it.